# display text with if/else statement if value not found in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to find a way of displaying an else or if statement in this code so that if the record/value doesn't exist in the mysql table then it will echo a piece of text like 'ask me'.

heres the code:

```
<?php
$rates_set = get_rates();
while ($rates = mysql_fetch_array($rates_set)) {
 ?>
 <table width="110%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="col">Rates</th>
    <th align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="col">money in</th>
    <th align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="col">money Out</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="row">cost</th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['labour']} "; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['material']}"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="row">cost/th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['money']}"; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['expense']}"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="row">Overnight</th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['charges']}"; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['fees']}"; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<?php }  ?>
```

hope someone can help. thank you.

Comment: Which field do you want to test for? For example you can do  `<td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php if !isset($rates['labour']) echo('Ask me') else echo"{$rates['labour']} "; ?></td>`

Comment: i get a syntax error if i use this :/

Comment: Try this :`<td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php if (!isset($rates['labour'])) echo('Ask me'); else echo($rates['labour']); ?></td>`

Comment: checkout my answer hope will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the values in the **$rates** array and if empty, assign a default:

```
$rates_set = get_rates();
while ($rates = mysql_fetch_array($rates_set)) {

   // Set defaults
   foreach($rates as $key => $value)
   {
      if(strlen(trim($value)) == 0)
      {
         // Assign default
         $rates[$key] = 'Ask Me';
      }
   } 
?>
```

There is some tweaking to be done with this method, such as how you determine a value is "empty"...but essentially, this will get the job done.

The other option is to handle it locally within the markup using the ternary operator:

```
<td align="center" valign="middle">£
    <?php isset($rates['money']) ? $rates['money'] : 'Ask Me'; ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php echo isset($rates['fees'])?"{$rates['fees']}":"ask me"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<?php
$rates_set = get_rates();
if(mysql_num_rows($rates_set)<1) {
    echo "Ask me";
 }else{
   while ($rates = mysql_fetch_array($rates_set)) {
     //your code
      }
    }
```

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($rates_set)<1) { "this is the way"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/* Use This */

$rates_set = get_rates();

if (mysql_num_rows($rates_set)>0) {


while ($rates = mysql_fetch_array($rates_set)) {
 ?>
 <table width="110%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="col">Rates</th>
    <th align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="col">money in</th>
    <th align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="col">money Out</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="row">cost</th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['labour']} "; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['material']}"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="row">cost/th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['money']}"; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['expense']}"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" scope="row">Overnight</th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['charges']}"; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">£<?php echo "{$rates['fees']}"; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<?php } 

} else {

echo 'Ask me';

}
  ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo ( (!empty($rates['labour'])) ? $rates['labour'] : 'Default Text'); ?>
```

Is that what you are looking for?

**Edit:**

Alter the top of the loop like this:

```
while ($rates = mysql_fetch_array($rates_set)) {
  if (empty($rates_set)) continue;
```

Comment: kind of yea, i want it to display the default text exactly like that but if the record isn't in the mysql table it won't show the table on the page :/

Comment: I didn't think it was you :) I am not sure why this post deserves a down vote. Maybe it is legitimate. If so, I would sure like to know why.